# Eclipse Plugin: Obtaining an IFile from String

Tags: eclipse, file, workspace

I am doing some serialization which also contains an IFile path that needs to be stored as string.

I am using this IFile in a plugin project. For debugging or running Eclipse starts a new workspace. This testing-workspace has its root somewhere relatively to the plugin folder. My problem is, when I turn my IFile to an absolute path, my Eclipse testing-workspace considers the file as outside the workspace and throws exceptions.
If I use the project relative path, the IFile creation from string fails and IFile is null.

I truly want to believe that it works the way I need it, but I really would like to see it. Is there a way to reconstruct a valid IFile from a project relative path?

Currently, I am doing the reconstruction from String->IFile like this:

```
//name is a string with the absolute path
      IPath location = new Path(name);
        IFile file = project.getFile(location.lastSegment());
```

But, like already mentioned, works only with an absolute path, which doesn't work in the eclipse testing-workspace.

Thanks for a hint

Answer (score 6):

You are very close. You want:

```
IPath path = new Path(name);
IFile file = project.getFile(path);
```

The name should be an absolute (to the workspace) or project-relative path. This interface is defined in IContainer.getFile(IPath). I changed the variable from "location" because location is usually meant as the actual (local) OS file path. To get the path use:

```
IPath path = file.getProjectRelativePath();
```